# Traversing a Composite Bézier Path

Tags: parametrization, bezier-curve

Does anyone know if there is a way to traverse a composite bezier path (a path made of multiple bezier curves) with a parameter $t$ such that $0 \le t \le 1$? Basically I want to traverse an entire composite Bézier path with a parameter $t$ instead of a single Bézier curve.

**Important**: $t$ should correspond relatively to how far along the path I am. This means that I can't just split the entire Bézier path into its Bézier curves and then figure out the index of the Bézier curve that I need to traverse based how big $t$ is because the Bézier curves could be of different lengths.

[image: Bezier curve with equally spaced dots (dashes)]

For example, in the image above you can see that the points are somewhat equally spaced. This is the desired effect. If I were to find the index of the Bézier curve that I want to traverse based on the path parameter $t$, I would get the same number of points for the shorter lines as I do for the longer lines.

*Ideally the algorithm should take $O(1)$ time to find a point along the curve (since I'll be using it to traverse many points)*

Comment: If the Bezier curves are defined parametrically, you can integrate (probably numerically) to get the length of each one, and then allocate parts of $t$'s range proportionally.

Comment: But then if I add to the end of the composite path then I will end up having to update the beginning and end `t` of each curve which will be O(m) where m is the number of curves. Also, each time I want to get the point for a certain `t` it will be O(logm) to find which curve I need to traverse. Is this the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: What are the degrees of your Bezier curves ? If they are all quadratic, it is not difficult to find out the arclength of a parabola

Comment: The largest degree I'm dealing with is cubic